# Are serial down-votings considered?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Like many other users, I lost more than 1100 Reps, some of which was the result of serial up-voting reversion!

- Did they consider same thing for serial down-voting?

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are. On other sites, it's not completely unusual for someone to respond an argument with someone else by downvoting the other person's posts. There are three things that slow people down:

1. Downvotes on answers result in a -1 penalty for the voter.
2. Downvotes don't actually cost much reputation for the recipient.
3. Folks tend to cool down after a while and realize it's just not worth the effort.

Also of note: downvotes given by deleted users are also reverted.

I'm sorry this happened to you; it really wasn't your fault in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your sympathy and for your civil response!